# How do I set WindowText on the Taskbar?

Tags: windows, winapi

```
const char* title = "old title";
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(title, title);
SetWindowText(hwnd, "new title");
```

This sets the title bar to "new title", but the caption in the task bar is still "old title".  How do I set both?

If relevant, this is being done in a DLL loaded in the process which owns the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should set both, window title and task bar item. Your call

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(title, title);
```

does not look good, first parameter has to be class name (look at [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx)). It looks to me that problem is somewhere else but I may be wrong.